# Convert String to Dictionary variable with right types

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I am creating a application where I have a Dictionary (which is produced from a specific cryptography algorithm) variable and save it to a text file. I retrieve the variable and convert it to Dictionary again like this:

```
f = open( '/sk.txt')
t_ref = f.read()
requested_encrypted_file = ast.literal_eval(t_ref)
print type(requested_encrypted_file)
f.close()
```

The Dictionary variable which contain the vital infos for the ciphertext has this form:

```
{'msg': '{"ALG": 0, "CipherText": "xcUHHV3ifPJKFqB8aL9fzQ==", "MODE": 2, "IV": "2Y2xDI+a7JRt7Zu6Vtq86g=="}', 'alg': 'HMAC_SHA1', 'digest': '4920934247257f548f3ca295455f5109c2bea437'}
```

The problem is that when I retrieve this variable from file all the fields are str and not the type they where before save it to a txt file? Is there a simple way to retrieve them with the correct types?

Any advice would be helpful and deeply appreciated.

Comment: How do you save the dictionary to the file?

Comment: Like this:  f = open('/sk.txt', 'w' )
         f.write(str(ciphertext))
         f.close()

Comment: If `ciphertext` contains the value you've shown, all the keys and values *are* strings.  Do you want the value type of key `msg` to be `dict`?  If so, the problem is generating the value being written to the file.  Your code works as is if you remove the single quotes around msg's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have to deal with basic data types, save and load your data JSON-serialized.

```
import json

a = {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 42, 'biz': True}

# Save
with open('test.txt', 'w') as outf:
    json.dump(a, outf)

# Read
with open('test.txt', 'r') as inf:
    b = json.load(inf)
```

`b` will be

> {'baz': 42, 'biz': True, 'foo': 'bar'}

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module to `dump` Python data structures as serializable data and then `load`.

```
pickle.dump(dictionary, open('data.p', 'w')) # write file with dictionary structure
savedData = pickle.load(open('data.p', 'r')) # reads the written file as dictionary
```